# How can I git fetch && git checkout from GitHub Actions using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-cli

I have the following GitHub Actions file `./github/workflows/staging-deploy.yml`

```
name: Deploy on Staging VM
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - staging
    types:
      - closed

permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
      
jobs: 
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Az CLI login'
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    - name: 'Run Azure CLI commands'
      run: |
          az vm run-command invoke -g rclco-app -n rclco-app-staging-vm --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "cd /app && git config --global --add safe.directory /app && git fetch && git checkout staging && sudo systemctl restart backend"
```

Unfortunately, this does not appear to do anything after the action runs (and succeeds) in GitHub Actions. If I replace

```
--scripts "cd /app && git config --global --add safe.directory /app && git fetch && git checkout staging && sudo systemctl restart backend"
```

with

```
--scripts "cd /app && mkdir testdir"
```

`/app/testdir` is created. It is showing a message that $HOME is not set, but I am unsure if that is the problem. Here is the output of my GitHub Actions:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran the your workflow even I received the same error after creating app directory with mkdir app refer below:-

```bash
sudo mkdir app
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Workflow Output Same error :-**

[image]

**In order to resolve this error, I set HOME as my environment variable by adding this command in my az vm run command :-**

```bash
export  HOME=/home/usernameoflinuxvm
```

After adding this command if you receive this error

```
message": "Enable succeeded: \n[stdout]\n\n[stderr]\nfatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git\n",
```

Just install git in your linux vm and initialize it in the app directory with `git init` command:-

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git -y
run git init after cd into app dir
cd /app && git init
```

If you get the below error add `git checkout -b staging` in your az vm run command.

```
Now getting this error "message": "Enable succeeded: \n[stdout]\n\n[stderr]\nerror: pathspec 'staging' did not match any file(s) known to git\n",
```

Make sure you create a `backend.service` file so that the systemctl restart backend command works successfully.

```bash
cd /etc/systemd/system/
sudo nano backend.service

backend.service code:-
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                backend.service
[Unit]  Description=Backend Service 
[Service]  ExecStart=/usr/bin/env bash -c 'cd pathtobackend && ./startupscript.sh'  
Restart=always
[Install]  WantedBy=multi-user.target

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable backend.service
```

This command switches the branch to staging:-

```bash
git checkout -b staging
```

**My github workflow:-**

```yaml
name: Azure VM

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Az CLI login'
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    - name: 'Run Azure CLI commands'
      run: |
            az vm run-command invoke -g siliconrg -n siliconvm --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "export HOME=/home/siliconuser && cd /app && git config --global --add safe.directory /app && git fetch && git checkout -b staging && sudo systemctl restart backend"
```

***Azure CLI command that runs git fetch, switches branch and restarts backend.***

az vm run command reference [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest)

```
 az vm run-command invoke -g siliconrg -n siliconvm --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "export HOME=/home/siliconuser && cd /app && git config --global --add safe.directory /app && git fetch && git checkout -b staging && sudo systemctl restart backend"
```

**Output Successful:-**

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much! The only extra input I have is (if it's a private repository) add:  



`env: GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`